# How to set frameset col value to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, frameset

This piece of code produces a page with two vertical columns:

```
<frameset id="set" cols="*,*">
    <frame id="frame1" src="index.html"> 
    <frame id="frame2" src="index2.html"> 
</frameset>
```

However, I want to be able to set the `cols` value independantly like this:

```
function setvalue(){   
    var framewidth=prompt("Enter the default right column width : ", "50%")
}
```

and then change the `cols` value... This is where my problem lies, I can't get the script right... Here's what it looks like:

```
<Script>
  document.getElementByid["set"].cols.value = framewidth;
</script>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things i see wrong in your code:

the document.`getElementById` is a function so it should be called like so:

```
document.getElementById("set");
```

secondly when you set value for attribute of an element, e.g. "cols" in your case, you should do it like so:

```
document.getElementById("set").cols = "20%, 80%"
```

I did a quick test in Firefox and this works:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function setvalue(){   
         var framewidth=prompt("Enter the default right column width : ", "50")

         var width = parseInt(framewidth);
         width = isNaN(width) ? 50 : width;

         var val = (100 - width) + "%, " + width + "%";

         document.getElementById("set").cols = val
      }

      window.onload = setvalue;
   </script>
</head>
<frameset id="set" cols="*,*">
    <frame id="frame1" src="index.html"> 
    <frame id="frame2" src="index2.html"> 
</frameset>
</html>
```

Set the value in prompt as: `80`